# Extracting baseline hazards from stpm2-object

Tags: r, survival

I need to extract the baseline hazards from a general survival model (GSM) that I've constructed using the rstpm2-package (a conversion of the stpm2 module in stata).

using the data in the rstpm2-package let's use this as an example:

```
library(rstpm2)

gsm <- stpm2(Surv(rectime,censrec==1)~hormon, data=brcancer, df=3)

sum.gsm <- summary(gsm)
```

So I've noticed that the summary has an element named bhazard:

```
sum.gsm@args$bhazard
```

However it seems to be filled with zeroes and holds one value per patient. As far as I understand the baseline hazard should consist of one hazard for every time-point in the data.

Does anyone have any experience that could be of assistance

Comment: I've removed the Stata tag. I can't see why this is of interest to Stata users, unless they happen to be R users, in which case that tag suffices.

Comment: I figured that as the package is originally developed for stata, they might hold some knowledge as to how this is done there.

Comment: Perhaps, but my experience is that while the main results are or should bevthe same, the details of any translation from one language to another are often quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plot` and `lines` methods to plot survival and a number of other predictions. For example:

```
plot(gsm, newdata=data.frame(hormon=0))
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgQvk.png)

Note that you need to specify the `newdata` argument. For more general plots, you can get predictions on a time `grid` with `full` covariates with standard errors using:

```
out <- predict(gsm,newdata=data.frame(hormon=0:1), grid=TRUE, 
               full=TRUE, se.fit=TRUE)
```

Then you could use `ggplot2` or `lattice` to plot the intervals. For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(out, aes(x=rectime, y=Estimate, ymin=lower, ymax=upper, 
                fill=factor(hormon))) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha=0.6) + geom_line()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnxxq.png)

Edit: to predict survival at specific times, you can include the times in the `newdata` argument:

```
predict(gsm, newdata=data.frame(hormon=0,rectime=1:365))
```

(Note that survival is defined in terms of log(time), hence I have excluded `rectime=0`.)

Comment: I think this brings me one step closer to what I really want to do. Do you know if there's a way to extract the baseline for specific timepoints? For example seq(0,365,1)?